# Очистка полей ввода

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

помогите пожалуйста решить задачу. Необходимо очистить 3000 полей на одной странице. Какой скрипт необходимо выполнить через инструменты разработчика (CONSOLE), что бы это осуществить? И возможно ли это? Поля которые справа на скриншоте нужно очистить от данных. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а эти поля в одной форме ?

Comment: Все в одном окне.

Comment: я не об окне говорю - а о том в одной `form` или нет ?

Comment: Нужно сразу во всех

Answer (score 1):

"3000 полей на одной странице" - Ваши пользователи Вас возненавидят.

---

```
$("input, select, textarea").val("");
```

Comment: да, что там пользователи. Я мимо проходил - мне страшно стало :D

Comment: Сработать то сработало но не совсем правильно( Не понимаю почему пользователи должны злится) Объясню суть. Перевожу шаблон для prestashop. В интернете нашел код позволяющий переносить уже переведенные строки в правые формы. Но он почему то переносил только там где не было перевода вообще... Вот поэтому и понадобился вот этот код, что бы убрать все. Теперь по коду - Все, что находится в ячейках он убирает. Но при нажатии сохранить все ровно остается прежний перевод. Даже если оставить пустым либо вставить рус перевод  в строки.

Comment: Что я делаю не так? Помогите пожалуйста. Сначала захожу и перевожу все строки с помощью Chrome. Потом использую код "$("input, select, textarea").val("");" Дабы удалить все с правых форм. Далее использую код "jQuery('tbody tr').each(function(i){
var vau = jQuery(this).find('input').val() || jQuery(this).find('textarea').val();
if(!vau){
jQuery(this).find('input').val(jQuery(this).find('td').eq(0).text());
jQuery(this).find('textarea').val(jQuery(this).find('td').eq(0).text());
//console.log(jQuery(this).find('td').eq(0).text());
}
});"  Но при сохранении все ровно остается все по старом